# I am trying to set the profile image and name in the navigation header but the code is not working

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The following code is used to to set the profile image and name, but it is not working and does not show any error on the logcat.  I want to add the image and name in header of navigation drawer. Kindly help.

```
 public class Admin_Dashboard_Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{
    
        private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
        private ActivityAdminDashboardBinding binding;
    
        CircleImageView profile_imageView;
        TextView profile_Name;
        RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
        List<FoodData> myFoodList;
        String profileImageUrl, userName;
        FoodData mFoodData;
        private ValueEventListener eventListener;
    
        DrawerLayout drawer;
        NavigationView navigationView;
        //
        DatabaseReference databaseReference;
        FirebaseAuth mAuth;
        FirebaseUser mUser;
        ///
        
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           // setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin_dashboard);
    
            binding = ActivityAdminDashboardBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
            setContentView(binding.getRoot());
    
            //
            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            mUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
            databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Profile_Credentials");
            ///
    
            setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarAdminDashboard.toolbar);
            binding.appBarAdminDashboard.fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Admin_Dashboard_Activity.this, Upload_Recipe.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
    
            drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    
    
           // View view = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header_admin_dashboard);
            profile_imageView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.profile_imageView);
            profile_Name = navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.profile_Name);
    
            databaseReference.child(mUser.getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.exists()){
                        profileImageUrl = snapshot.child("itemImage").getValue().toString();
                        userName = snapshot.child("itemName").getValue().toString();
                        Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(profileImageUrl).into(profile_imageView);
                     //   Picasso.get().load(profileImageUrl).into(profile_imageView);
                        profile_Name.setText(userName);
                    }
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(Admin_Dashboard_Activity.this, "Sorry!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

I think I used the correct method for retriving, but still don't show any result.

Comment: Is your onDataChange triggered?

Comment: What do you mean by by triggered?

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on `if (snapshot.exists()){` and run the app in a debugger, does it reach that breakpoint?

Comment: Or, if you try to log the value of `profileImageUrl`, are you getting something printed out in the logcat?

Comment: No, there is no thing on the logcat